# Box2d javascript revolute joint same anchor point different bodies

Tags: javascript, box2d, physics, game-physics

I'm trying to make a rag doll and I have 2 hip joints implemented as revolute joints. The problem is that they are not responding as independent segments. It seems like one of them is holding up the other one. It looks like this:
[image: Hip joint bug]

If I take out one of the legs, the other falls freely.

There are no limits on the joint angles.
I've tried setting the collision flags and mask bits for all the segments to 0 so that they won't collide with anything but that doesn't seem to work. 
I've put the collide connected property of the revolute joint to false as well..
I'm not too sure what else I can do. 
Is there a taboo against putting two revolute joints in the same location where they are both connected to the same segment?